# python shutil copy function missing last few lines

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

I have a python script that generates a large text file that needs a specific filename that will FTPd later.  After creating the file it copies it to a new location while modifying the date to reflect the date sent.  The only problem is that the copied file is missing several of the last lines of the original.

```
from shutil import copy

// file 1 creation

copy("file1.txt", "backup_folder/file1_date.txt")
```

What might be causing this?  Could the original file not be finished being written to causing the copy to just get what is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must make sure that whatever creates `file1.txt` has *closed* the file handle.

File writing is buffered, and if you do not close the file, the buffer is not flushed. The missing data at the end of a file is still sitting in that buffer.

Preferably you ensure that the file is closed by using the file object as a context manager:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as openfile:
    # write to openfile

# openfile is automatically closed once you step outside the `with` block.
```

Comment: I new it was something simple that I was missing. Added a close file right before the copy and it fixed it.